# Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: 'NSApplication' is undefined

Tags: objective-c

the code shown below gives an exeption

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface Main : NSObject { }
@end
@implementation Main
+(void)main
{
  NSLog(@"Hello world!");
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSApplication *anApplication = nil;
  NSArray *screenArray = nil;               
  NSEnumerator *screenEnumerator = nil;
  NSScreen *aScreen = nil;
  NSWindowDepth *depths = null;//remove const
  BOOL exactMatch = NO;

  anApplication = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  screenArray = [NSScreen screens];
  screenEnumerator = [screenArray objectEnumerator];
}
@end
```

i am using windows and please go through the link below qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot done it with http://qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC

just go through the compiler  http://www.gnustep.org

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try</s>

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

I don't think your imports include the header for NSApplication.

That was wrong.  Actually, I think the problem is that you haven't called [NSApplicationMain()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000695-SW12).  It doesn't really make sense to have an application object if you don't have an application (with a user interface). If you don't want a UI, you might get away with using [NSApplicationLoad()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000695-SW11).

Also make sure you are linking the AppKit framework.

Comment: @appu: No.  `NSApplicationLoad()` and `NSApplicationMain()` are functions, not objects.  You have to one of them tocreate an instance of NSApplication.

Comment: @appu: No.  `int sucess = NSApplicationLoad();`

Comment: i am using windows and please go through the link below http://www.qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC

Comment: @appu: I don't think I can help you any further.  I've never used the compiler you linked to.  I wouldn't be at all surprised if it is not fully featured.

Comment: ok.thank you for your support and guidance.which platform you using.can i make the above program in windows using another compiler?

Answer (score 0):

your compiler does not have capabilities for ui
you just go with http://qckapp.com/index.html?p=ObjC only for basics
try gnustep

good luck.